# How to extract white blobs from noise background?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

*I have an image such as this one :*

[image: Noisy image]

As you can see, it is very noisy. I would like to extract the coordinates of white blobs and their signal-to-noise ratio (how distinct the blob is from noise).

**Which way should I go to solve this problem ? Are there any existing algorithms at my disposal ?**

*Please note I know how to extract the coordinates of a blob when it is contoured and how to denoise images, but in this case the noise is so intense I couldn't it make it work properly.
Also, I have at my disposal multiple shots of the same blobs with different noise, if it helps, but I cannot average as blobs move relative to each other over time.*

Comment: first of all you should try to get images with less noise. for example by averaging multiple images (if noise changes over time). then you should define some threshold. what is blob and what is noise (what density is necessary?)

Comment: @Piglet I don't want to threshold, because the blobs I'm interested in are very likely to be erased as they have a very low S/N ratio. Furthermore, they are moving in time, so averaging will just delete the faster-moving ones and keep the slow ones :(

Comment: @DavyM I am asking for algorithmic advice, not coding advice, and this is why I didn't show any code I tried as I don't really know where to go. I had some ideas, like thresholding and averaging like Piglet proposed, but it all failed.

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=58fc532feeae3932cf13acf6&assetKey=AS%3A486205679771650%401492931875494) maybe?

Comment: @Miki yes, exactly !

Comment: @magix I am not talking about a intensity threshold. you have to distinguish between what you want and what you don't want. from what I see a blob is just a cluster of dense pixels so what is the minimum density for a blob? think about it

Comment: Try median filters of different sizes

Answer (score 3):

I think a morphological opening as suggested by @WillHeitman gives a pretty good starting point. I just did this at the command-line with **ImageMagick**

```
convert noise.png -threshold 80% -morphology open diamond result.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want a quick-and-dirty solution, you could try eroding and then dilating. The erosion would remove the smaller pieces, and the dilation would recover the larger chunks. Tinkering the parameters should get the results you're looking for. After that, your image should be de-noised, at which point you can extract the coords from the contoured blobs. Hope this helps!

Comment: This method erases many of the low SNR blobs, and gives really bad results because of the high-intensity noise :/ Thank you for answering :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to process this in ImageMagick using connected components. First I blur the image a little, then threshold. Then throw out regions smaller than 10 pixels in area. The connected components tells me the bounding box, centroid, area and color.

```
convert input.png -blur 0x1 -threshold 85% -type bilevel +write tmp1.png -define connected-components:verbose=true -define connected-components:area-threshold=10 -define connected-components:mean-color=true -connected-components 8 objects.gif
```

Here is the tmp1.png image to see what the threshold looks like:

[image: thresholdd result]

Here is the result of the connected components:

[image: connected components result]

Here is the information about the regions:

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 254x158+0+0 125.9,78.8 39619 gray(0)
  6: 18x17+205+34 213.6,42.3 241 gray(255)
  14: 12x12+229+91 234.6,97.0 108 gray(255)
  1: 12x10+32+0 37.7,4.0 63 gray(255)
  5: 4x5+11+19 12.4,20.9 17 gray(255)
  16: 6x4+19+106 21.4,107.8 17 gray(255)
  18: 4x6+194+116 195.5,118.5 17 gray(255)
  8: 4x5+242+56 243.8,58.2 16 gray(255)
  12: 3x5+68+82 69.0,83.8 12 gray(255)
  17: 4x4+182+109 183.6,110.8 12 gray(255)
```

where gray(0) is black and gray(255) is white.

Now if you want to know the average background in the input image excluding these regions, you can do:

```
convert input.png \( objects.gif -negate \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:255*u]\n" info:
```

which returns: 160.105 in the range 0 to 255. In ImageMagick if you scale an image that is transparent to 1 pixel and get its value, ImageMagick does the average in the -scale function ignoring transparent pixels. So I have used the binary objects.gif as a mask an put its inverse (negate) into the alpha channel of the input image to exclude the mask regions from the average.

Now if you want to get the average color of each region and then some measure of the signal to noise, you can get the ratio of the color of the region to the color of the background and express that as percent. Note that I use the bounding box of the region in the output image as the alpha channel of the bounding box of the region in the input image to get the region's average color. Then take the ratio with the average background color and convert to percent. (Unix syntax)

```
OFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
arr=(`convert input.png -blur 0x1 +write tmp1.png -threshold 85% -type bilevel +write tmp2.png \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=10 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 tmp3.png | sed 's/^[ ]*//' | tail -n +3`)
bckavg=`convert input.png \( tmp3.png -negate \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:u]" info:`
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
bbox=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d\  -f2`
cent=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d\  -f3`
area=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d\  -f4`
snr=`convert input.png[$bbox] tmp3.png[$bbox] -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:100*u/$bckavg]\n" info:`
echo "centroid=$cent area=$area snr=$snr%"
done
IFS=$OFS
```

Which lists:

```
centroid=213.6,42.3 area=241 snr=156.745%
centroid=234.6,97.0 area=108 snr=155.258%
centroid=37.7,4.0 area=63 snr=152.072%
centroid=12.4,20.9 area=17 snr=153.319%
centroid=21.4,107.8 area=17 snr=149.644%
centroid=195.5,118.5 area=17 snr=151.63%
centroid=243.8,58.2 area=16 snr=154.235%
centroid=69.0,83.8 area=12 snr=152.555%
centroid=183.6,110.8 area=12 snr=153.076%
```

Or you can express the (power) signal to noise in decibels as:

```
OFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
arr=(`convert input.png -blur 0x1 +write tmp1.png -threshold 85% -type bilevel +write tmp2.png \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=10 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 tmp3.png | sed 's/^[ ]*//' | tail -n +3`)
bckavg=`convert input.png \( tmp3.png -negate \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:u]" info:`
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
bbox=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d\  -f2`
cent=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d\  -f3`
area=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d\  -f4`
snr=`convert input.png[$bbox] tmp3.png[$bbox] -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:10*log((u/$bckavg)*(u/$bckavg))]\n" info:`
echo "centroid=$cent area=$area snr=$snr db"
done
IFS=$OFS
```

Which lists:

```
centroid=213.6,42.3 area=241 snr=3.90389 db
centroid=234.6,97.0 area=108 snr=3.82108 db
centroid=37.7,4.0 area=63 snr=3.64098 db
centroid=12.4,20.9 area=17 snr=3.7119 db
centroid=21.4,107.8 area=17 snr=3.50118 db
centroid=195.5,118.5 area=17 snr=3.61568 db
centroid=243.8,58.2 area=16 snr=3.76365 db
centroid=69.0,83.8 area=12 snr=3.66856 db
centroid=183.6,110.8 area=12 snr=3.69812 db
```

EDIT: Here is a slightly more efficient version that does not require the bounding box processing. It gets the average color of the region directly by add -fuzz to the process.

```
OFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
arr=(`convert input.png -blur 0x1 +write tmp1.png -black-threshold 85% +write tmp2.png \
\( -clone 0 -threshold 0 +write tmp3.png +delete \) \
-fuzz 15% \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=10 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 tmp3.png | sed 's/^[ ]*//' | tail -n +3`)
bckavg=`convert input.png \( tmp3.png -negate \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:255*u]" info:`
echo "bckavg=$bckavg"
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
cent=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d\  -f3`
area=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d\  -f4`
graylevel=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | sed -n 's/^.*gray[(]\([0-9]*\)[)]$/\1/p'`
snr=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:10*log(($graylevel/$bckavg)*($graylevel/$bckavg))]\n" info:`
echo "centroid=$cent area=$area graylevel=$graylevel snr=$snr db"
done
IFS=$OFS
```

Here is the listing:

```
centroid=213.6,42.3 area=241 graylevel=246 snr=3.72702 db
centroid=234.6,97.0 area=108 graylevel=242 snr=3.58463 db
centroid=37.7,4.0 area=63 graylevel=235 snr=3.32968 db
centroid=12.4,20.9 area=17 graylevel=231 snr=3.18056 db
centroid=21.4,107.8 area=17 graylevel=228 snr=3.06702 db
centroid=195.5,118.5 area=17 graylevel=227 snr=3.02884 db
centroid=243.8,58.2 area=16 graylevel=227 snr=3.02884 db
centroid=69.0,83.8 area=12 graylevel=222 snr=2.83538 db
centroid=183.6,110.8 area=12 graylevel=228 snr=3.06702 db
```

Resulting values are slightly different for the snr.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Setchell answer but was intrigued by your wish to get a signal to noise ratio (SNR)

I think the first step is to **define what the perfect signal is**.  Then you can compare that perfect signal with your data.

For example, I defined a perfect signal to be a Gaussian matrix with sigma=1 with dimensions that match your image.

[image]

Then **perform a [phase correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation) between your original image and your perfect signal**.  The phase correlation algorithm is roughly:

1. take the Fourier Transform (fft) of original image
2. take Conjugate of the fft of the second image (perfect blob)
3. multiply results from (1) and (2)
4. take inverse fft of result (3)

The result from step (4) is illustrated in the image below.

[image]

Okay, I know that doesn't look great BUT what is cool is that **the values of phase correlation result are effectively [coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(signal_processing)) values that tell you how similar your original image is to the perfect image.**  a value of 1 is a perfect match while a value of -1 is a perfect mismatch.

From here you could do some cool tricks like finding not the points/pixels but the regions/areas that have the highest coherence values.

Let me know if my answer was confusing or you have any questions! Good luck!

Comment: awesome work ! I'll try to build up on this and will keep you updated :)